# React, Gulp. Не загружаются стили

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gulp

Пишу приложение с использованием React, Node, Gulp. Возникла проблема с подключением стилей в компонент. В Webpack знаю что существует специальные плагины. Что есть для Gulp?

Вот что подключаю в файле компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

Стили подключаются но как простой файл а не стили.

При запуске этого task-а в gulp-e:

```
 gulp.task('react', () => {
    var appBundler = browserify({
        entries: './src/main.jsx',
        debug: true
    });

    appBundler.transform('babelify', {compact: true, presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']})
        .bundle().on('error',gutil.log)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

в конесоле выводит вот эту ошибку:

```
...\node_modules\react-select\dist\react-select.css:8
.Select {
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Есть какоето решение чтобы с помощю gulp подключать стили в компонент?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую использовать [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) для создания проекта на React. Он основывается на Webpack, но сама конфигурация скрывается под капотом.

Импорт стилей происходит без каких либо настроек:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

будет работать "из коробки". Также если дополнительно установить [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), то можно использовать **SASS / SCSS / LESS** файлы:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
import 'my-custom-styles.scss';
```